# display row names and colnames in r shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to see the names of my column in my dashboard.

In my file ui.R, I tried to put `row.names=TRUE`  but it doesn't work.

```
dashboardBody( 
      tabItems( tabItem(tabName="OP",(tableOutput("moyenne",rownames=TRUE)))))
```

and in my file.R :

```
shinyServer(function(input,output){

 output$moyenne <- renderTable({
 (moyenne)

})
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You want to pass `rownames = TRUE` to `renderTable`, not `tableOutput`:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tableOutput("moyenne")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$moyenne <- renderTable({
    moyenne
  }, rownames = TRUE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```